# How can i make a simple counter in React without using state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a simple app that counts the number of times the button has been clicked. I read this is a good first question in JS interviews.
"Ask the candidate to build a click counter using any popular framework (React preferred in 2020). This ridiculously simple app has one job: keep track of how many times the user has clicked the button during the current session. No storage. No network I/O. Just count clicks. It is intentionally ridiculously simple"
My first instinct would be to use hooks, but the question wants the programmer to do it without using storage which I believe includes using state.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {

 let count=0;

 const add=()=>{
    debugger;
    count++;
  }

  return (
      <header className="App-header">
      <button onClick={()=>add()}>click me</button>
      {count}
      </header>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is what I tried. Using debugger I can see count does go up but the changes aren't showing on the page. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: State and storage are very different. In fact, state is ephemeral in react so that shouldn't be an issue. If they're asking this in an interview, then using state is probably what they're looking for you to use as it's one of the core concepts of react

Comment: I highly doubt they mean for you to not use state.

Comment: In React state is not storage..

Comment: Devil's advocate.... state is stored in memory. :p

Comment: You should be fine with state. Just go with  `const [count, setCount] = useState(0);`

Comment: You made my day dude

Comment: Yeah, I think I might have misinterpreted the question. Thank you all for your responses! Hooks seem to be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

React is a JS library so we can use pure js:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 id="c">0</h1>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          let c = document.getElementById("c");
          c.innerHTML = parseInt(c.textContent)+1;
        }}
      >
        +
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: As you can see, this will work if the requirement is truly to not use state. However, please don't use this pattern for any other reason. It defeats the purpose of using React in the first place. Two of the main features of React are to allow for a declarative UI (which we abandon by setting the `innerHTML`) and to manage state updates (which we abandon by not using state where it makes sense to).

Comment: @BrianThompson Yes, It is adverse!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems I misinterpreted the article's question but this does solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code doesn't produce the expected result is that React doesn't update the dom unless it sees that an update is necessary, i.e., because the state of the component changed.

So, in your case, the component only gets rendered once, when the value of `count` is 0. If you want to React to re-render the component and show you the new value, you'll have to trigger that with a state change. Alternatively you can follow cybercoder's solution, which actually opts out of React by supplying its own `innerHTML`.